# Can Gson's custom serializers and deserializers get the class/field?

Tags: java, json, gson

I am considering switching over to Gson.

From my beginner's knowledge, I know of two ways to implement custom serializers and deserializers:

1. `JsonSerializer` and `JsonDeserializer`, and
2. `TypeAdaptor`.

Consider the following:

```java
public class Pojo {
  @JsonAdaptor(MyCustomAdaptor.class)
  private Integer number;
}

class MyCustomAdaptor extends TypeAdaptor<Integer> {
  @Override
  public Integer read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
    // ...
  }

  public void write(JsonWriter writer, Integer value) throws IOException {
    // ...
  }
}
```

I noticed that `TypeAdaptor` does not expose the `Field` of `number`. Nor is this the case with `JsonSerializer` and `JsonDeserializer`. I understand that by the time these classes are used in the marshaling/unmarshalling lifecycle, there is no need to know this information.

For a moment, let's pretend that the `Field` was exposed in `TypeAdaptor`s. The following is a basic example of what I would do:

```java
public class Pojo {
  @JsonAdaptor(MyCustomAdaptor.class)
  @FloatSerialize
  private Number number;
}

class MyCustomAdaptor extends TypeAdaptor<Number> {
  @Override
  public Number read(JsonReader in, Field field) throws IOException {
    // Do something if @FloatSerialize is present.
  }

  public void write(JsonWriter writer, Number value, Field field) throws IOException {
    // Do something if @FloatSerialize is present.
  }
}
```

*I know this would not make sense because `@JsonAdaptor` can be used on classes and fields.*

Also, I know there are better ways to accomplish the above example; it is just an example and is meaningless. Basically, I want to use annotations, on a per-field basis, to tell custom serializers/deserializers how to process.

Is this possible with Gson? Can you create a custom serializer/deserializer that exposes the annotated class/field/etc?

Comment: Not possible in Gson. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66260322/same-type-serialization-based-on-field-name-in-gson-without-annotations for an alternative solution that probably might be developed to accomplish your needs.

Comment: Another solution to get rid of annotations like `@FloatSerialize` is implementing a base (probably abstract) type adapter that can be enhanced for concrete types, and then applied to concrete fields using `@JsonAdapter` (say, `abstract class CustomAdapter<T>`, `class FloatCustomAdapter extends CustomAdapter<Float>`, `@JsonAdapter(FloatCustomAdapter.class)`).

Comment: @fluffy Thank you for your response, but that is not the point of my post. The example I gave was a meaningless one. I am asking if you can create a custom serializer/deserializer that exposes the class/field?

Comment: I don't see _how_ it really differs from what you're asking. As I told: you can't as it's not possible in Gson, but _somehow_ possible via type adapter factories when creating type adapters per a single type, not even a class, (even parameterized). Exposing fields is much trickier since Gson `ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory` cannot be customized or enhanced like that. If it is not exactly the same what you're looking for, then does it mean workarounds aren't accepted? Well, okay.

Comment: @fluffy Thank you for that explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@JsonAdaptor(MyCustomAdaptor.class)
private Integer number;
```

You've annotated an Integer field.

> I noticed that TypeAdaptor does not expose the Field of number

I think there is something you misunderstand.

You provide the TypeAdaptor, you gives it the same type as your field:

`class MyCustomAdaptor extends TypeAdaptor<Integer>`

Then at serialization, you have the java objet you've annotated as an input to serialize to a string, then you have your field directly available as 'value' in a parameter:

`public void write(JsonWriter writer, Integer value) throws IOException`

At deserialization, you have a json string as input to deserialize to the object you've annotated. In the type adaptor this object is your field, that's why read method return an Integer.

`Integer read(JsonReader in) throws IOException`

It's up to you to return an Integer from the JsonReader.

You can use a Number instead of an Integer for your field, then you can have float,integer,short and more in your field.

For this you bring a NumberAdaptor:

```
class MyCustomAdaptor extends TypeAdaptor<Number> {
   
    Number read(JsonReader in, Field field) throws IOException;
    
    void write(JsonWriter writer, Number value) throws IOException; 
}
```

If you really want to think about 'field', then provide an adaptor for the whole objet:

```
class Pojo Adaptor extends TypeAdaptor< Pojo > {

  Pojo read(JsonReader in) throws IOException;

  void write(JsonWriter writer, Pojo value) throws IOException;
}
```

Then you have access to the whole object and its fields in the adaptor.

Same things form JsonSerializer/JsonDeserialize.

Comment: Thank you for your response. As I mentioned in my question, the example I gave does not make sense. I am asking if you can create a custom serializer/deserializer that exposes the class/field? I've updated my question.

Comment: You can write a serializer for the whole object, then you gain access to its fields. With reflection youvcan access annotations on these fields and do what you want

Answer (score 0):

With your additional info:

```
class Pojo Adaptor extends TypeAdaptor< Pojo > {

  Pojo read(JsonReader in) throws IOException{
for(Field f: Pojo.class.getDeclaredFields()){
            f.steAccessible();
            for(Annotation a : f.getAnnotations()){
                // Do what you want here withe the field and its annotation
            }
    }

  void write(JsonWriter writer, Pojo value) throws IOException{

        for(Field f: Pojo.class.getDeclaredFields()){
            f.steAccessible();
            for(Annotation a : f.getAnnotations()){
                // Do what you want here with the field and its annotation
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've wrote this from my memory but you've got the idea

Comment: I was hoping there was a per-field solution, but thank you.

Comment: See this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/66306480/2710704