# Jackson process string if annotated

Tags: java, jackson

If the field has an annotation, I need to replace all the & characters in the string with § when deserializing, and do the opposite when serializing

For example i created an annotation and marked a field with it

```java
public class SomeData {
    @MinecraftColorText
    private String str;
}
```

I need read this json:

```json
{"str":"&6Some nice text"}
```

and in java object str field need be: `§6Some nice text`

Im need process only annotated fields, not all String

I wanted to do it with `ContextualSerializer`, but as I understand it, it replaces the standard serialization

Answer (score 0):

So you should change your custom annotation `@MinecraftColorText` and add serialize and deserialize convertors:

```
@JsonDeserialize(converter = MinecraftDeserializeConverter.class)
@JsonSerialize(converter = MinecraftSerializeConverter.class)
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target(FIELD)
@JacksonAnnotationsInside
public @interface MinecraftColorText {
}
```

Deserialize converter:

```
public class MinecraftDeserializeConverter extends StdConverter<String, String> {

    @Override
    public String convert(final String s) {
        return s.replaceAll("&", "§");
    }
}
```

Serialize converter:

```
public class MinecraftSerializeConverter extends StdConverter<String, String> {

    @Override
    public String convert(final String s) {
        return s.replaceAll("§", "&");
    }
}
```

and just use:

```
  @MinecraftColorText
  private String str;
```

p.s: Don't forget about `@JacksonAnnotationsInside` that notify `jackson` about your custom serialization action.
See more [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations)

Comment: Ok thanks, but how to register annotation in objectmapper ?

Comment: That's all. Jackson will see your annotation with @JacksonAnnotationsInside and the correct handle it

Comment: Why are you using `replaceAll()`? `replace()` is the better choice - you don’t need regex here.

Comment: Another question, how i can also deserialize List<String> with this annotation, or im need create new one?